# NSString initWithBytes using swift

Tags: swift, nsstring

Trying to convert (working) objC code:

```
const uint8_t * buffer = ...
NSString * password = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer+28 length:buffer[27] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

tried:

```
let buffer: [Byte] = ...
var password = NSString(bytes: buffer+28, length: Int(buffer[27]), encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

but this crashes SourceKitService immediately, and the compiler if I try to compile.

I suspect it's maybe something to do with converting pointers?

Comment: (Ptr+28) actually translates into a subarray call.  You can't do pointer arithmetic on a swift array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If what you need is convert a byte array to NSString, then just construct it with

```
NSString(bytes: buffer, length: buffer.length, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

If you need to do pointer advance etc, then convert it to UnsafePointer like following:

```
NSString(bytes: UnsafePointer<Byte>(buffer) + 28, length: Int(buffer[27]), encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```